# Why do we link an azure storage account to a cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Why do we link an azure storage account to a cloud service? How does it help? What happens if I do not link them?

Comment: Can you provide some more details?  You don't have to have both a storage account and a cloud service.  You can create a cloud service without a storage account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Easier management - you have better idea of what is your overall configuration for a particular deployment
2. Easier management - upon deleting a resource you are being asked whether you want to delete the linked resources also

By the way, you can also link a Windows Azure SQL Database to a Cloud Service.

The whole idea is to help you better manage the services. There is no other reason and nothing will happen if you do not link. But think a bit - if you manage 3 subscriptions, 2 cloud services deployments each, 2 storage accounts per deployment. That is 6 cloud services, 12 storage accounts. Can you easily tell which service is using which account?

Answer (score 2):

The cloud service depends on the storage account.  When deploying the cloud service it will create a container called vsdeploy with a block blob that is used for the VMs it creates.

It also stores crash dump files there as well under the container wad-crashdumps.  The folder structure is WAD{GUID}{worker role}{instance}.  Then it will store all the .dmp files as block blobs.

Comment: I think this is a more correct answer to this question.